# Extract final value from nested field collection

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type with a **field collection**. This field collection has, as fields, other field collections. It works well, it groups the content for a node perfectly, but when trying to extract the data programmatically, I cannot access the values introduced. How would be the method. I tried with this piece of code, but it throws an error. Also not sure if adequate to my case (nested field collections):

```
$node = node_load($node->nid);
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

foreach ($node_wrapper->field_rich_text_group as $field_collection_wrapper) {
            $field_collection = $field_collection_wrapper->value();
                print_r($field_collection);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$node = node_load($node->nid);
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

foreach ($node_wrapper->field_rich_text_group->value() as $value) {
  $field_collection_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $value);
  $field_collection_myfield = $field_collection_wrapper->field_myfield->value();
  print_r($field_collection_myfield);
}
```

**Field Collection** is an entity, so if you want to access its field you have to pass the field collection in `entity_metadata_wrapper`. Then you can access the value of your fields in field collection like you do with your `$node_wrapper`

Comment: I have tried, but still an error and does not return the expected values. I am going to start from the beginning, with a single level field collection, and so on... I'll be back to report. Thanks anyway, surely you are right but I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the value by direct access.

```
$node = node_load($node->nid);
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
echo $node_wrapper->field_rich_text_group->field_meta_datos->field_meta_title->value();
```

I guess that the foreach would be needed if I have multivalued data.
Please someone explains to me why this solution works and `pbonnefoi` does not print anything and throws error. Adapting from his code,

```
$node = node_load($node->nid);
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
foreach ($node_wrapper->field_rich_text_group->value() as $value) {

$field_collection_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $value);

 $field_collection_myfield = entity_metadata_wrapper("field_collection_item", $field_collection_wrapper->field_meta_datos->value());

print $field_collection_myfield->field_meta_title->value();
```

Print OK but throws this error, probably because in the loop there is something it does not locate:

```
`// EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_meta_datos. en EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line 335 of /home/public_html/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).`
```

Comment: What is meta_datos ? Is it a field collection ?

Comment: Yes. What is even worst; Now I am not able to reproduce the structured jerarchy above. I have come to the final strcuture: ` $node_wrapper->field_seo->field_seo_com->field_seo_general->field_meta_title->value() just for having seo boxes for several domains. Instead of two levels I have 4 levels and cannot get it working with less. **I am not understanding the nested field collection.**

Comment: Are your field collection set to multiple ? In that case you have to use nested foreach.

Comment: No. it is multiple levels, not multiple values. I do these steps: In the content type, I create field_seo_general (embedded) and field_seo (hidden) just to get them available. In the field_seo which is the last level, I create the field field_meta_title. In field_seo_general I create field__com and field__us, which are field collection. Then, editing these two, I assign existing field, which is the type field_seo. So I can access via `echo $node_wrapper->field_seo_general->field__com->field_seo->field_meta_title->value();` . There are no multiple values. I am doing right? It is so convoluted.

Comment: Well I have to say I have trouble understanding your problem. For me you only use field collection if you need multiple instance of a group of field ?

Comment: My problem is that I thought I had too many levels. In fact, I think I have the correct number. The first one is the node. The second the field, which is a field collection, of SEO data for different domains (Domain Access node). The third level is one of the domains, and finally I have fourth level which is the field collection of metadata fields, and the last and fifth level is the data itself. The fourth level is necessary if I don't want to repeat the fields for every domain field collection, so now I think I understand it all. But `entity_metadata_wrapper` would be needed just once.